# how stop thread in python without stopping flag

Tags: python, multithreading, thread-safety, python-multithreading

I am using python thread to work on data process.Now I need to stop the thread that has been satrtted, While there is no stop singal in my run() method in RollingTaskHandler. So I am wondering whether there is a direct way to stop a thread ? I dir the Thread method and find some methods,does anyone use these methods?

```
> >>> from threading import Thread
> >>> dir(Thread) ['_Thread__bootstrap', '_Thread__bootstrap_inner', '_Thread__delete', '_Thread__exc_clear', '_Thread__exc_info',
> '_Thread__initialized', '_Thread__stop', '__class__', '__delattr__',
> '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__',
> '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__',
> '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__',
> '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_block', '_note',
> '_reset_internal_locks', '_set_daemon', '_set_ident', 'daemon',
> 'getName', 'ident', 'isAlive', 'isDaemon', 'is_alive', 'join', 'name',
> 'run', 'setDaemon', 'setName', 'start']



from baymax.views.upgrade import RollingTaskHandler    
 threads=[]
 arg ={...}
 rolling_task_thread = RollingTaskHandler(arg)
 threads.append(rolling_task_thread)


from threading import Thread
class RollingTaskHandler(Thread):
```

Comment: What you want to do is called "suspending", which should help you in your research. And no, there is no built-in function for that. BTW: Yes, someone uses these methods, even if not directly for some.

Comment: can u give a code example for suspending in python thread?

Comment: I probably could. Have you searched the web? That's why I told you the name of this thing, so you can research the this topic yourself. I didn't want to give you a lecture nor did I want to do your homework.

Comment: I google the suspend in python, suspend is just for python process not for thread